# Iterator to return list

Tags: java, list, foreach, iterator

I am trying to implement this with the help of enhanced for loop, but my question is if I use the iterator for the example below how do I make sure that my return type is picking up the corresponding value of "XYZ"?

```
List<Apples> a1 = new List<Apples>();
if(a1.iterator().next().equals("XYZ")
{
   return a1.iterator().next().getFruits();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use an iterator here? a simple `get()` will do the trick:

```
if (a1.get(0).equals("XYZ")) {
    return a1.get(0).getFruits();
}
```

Of course, if you intend to traverse all the elements in a list then you're missing a `for` here. And besides, your code won't work: it's a list of *apples*, you can't compare an apple with a string! Perhaps you meant something like this, replace `getStringAttribute()` with the appropriate attribute that you intend to compare with `"XYZ"`:

```
for (Apple a : a1) {
    if ("XYZ".equals(a.getStringAttribute())) {
        return a.getFruits();
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use get(0), wouldn't it pick the first element always ?

Comment: @sagar492 yes, and that's exactly what `a1.iterator().next()` does in a list: when you create a new iterator, the iteration starts over at the first element.

Comment: @Keppil no, OP is creating two iterators, they will both return the first element

Comment: I need to iterate over the list and eventually come to a point that matches "XYZ" and when it does i need to the getFruits method of that which has the same value something like this

Comment: a1.getService.iterator.next.equals("XYZ"), then gives me a1.getService.iterator.next.getFruits Can i use this ?

Comment: thanks i think i found the answer an suggested above

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want to implement the following

```
List<Apples> apples = new List<Apples>();
for(Apple a : apples) {
 if("xyz".equals(a.getSomethingWhatReturnsString())) return a.getFruits();
}
```